# Css hover on a div causes the div beside it to become smaller?

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone I'm making divs that are hoverable and are a certain width and height. They sit in a table beside each other and under each other(4 divs placed within a table in a td element) the issue I'm having is that everytime I hover over a div that has another one placed next to it when it opens it causes the div beside to become smaller(?) I'm not even sure whats happening but it just causes it to shrink within the td and the entire td expands. 
I was wondering if theres a way to make the td and div stay fixed in size(small and not cause the td to expand whenever the one beside it is expanding.

for example if i hover over the div with the text 2 the one with with the text 1 will stay closed(how it looks when you dont hover on anything

*I can only use css & html and I cant use an id-Important to say cause for some reason the site Im editing on won't let an id for some reason*

thanks in advance to all the helpers!

```css
.Scrollbox
        {
            background:rgba(237, 41, 57,0.6);
            width:300px;
            height:250px;
            border:1px solid #ffffff;
            overflow-y: scroll;
             position: relative;
             transition: height 1s ease;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; 
            
        }
        
        .Scrollbox:hover
        {
            height:500px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
```

```html
<table><tr><td><div class="Scrollbox">1</div></td><td><div class="Scrollbox">2</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="Scrollbox">3</div></td><td><div class="Scrollbox">4</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you just need to remove `transition: height 1s ease;` (if I understand correctly)

Comment: ...and make the heights the same.

Comment: Let me tell you a secret, there is nothing shrinking... The div you hover over is just growing from 250px to 500px, it just looks like the other ones shrink..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not getting smaller, it's moving down.  The default vertical alignment for table rows is 'middle'.  I added some CSS to keep table rows top-aligned.

```css
.Scrollbox
        {
            background:rgba(237, 41, 57,0.6);
            width:300px;
            height:250px;
            border:1px solid #ffffff;
            overflow-y: scroll;
             position: relative;
             transition: height 1s ease;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; 
        }
        
        .Scrollbox:hover
        {
            height:500px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        tr {
            vertical-align:top;
        }
```

```html
<table><tr><td><div class="Scrollbox">1</div></td><td><div class="Scrollbox">2</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="Scrollbox">3</div></td><td><div class="Scrollbox">4</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why add the `overflow-y: scroll;` at all? It's useless here, as the `td` is not becoming scrollable.

Comment: @adpro Who knows?  It's in the original question, without the complete story, I'd rather not speculate the necessity of the properties if they're unrelated to the apparent issue.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  That question was more for the OP.  I got thrown by it assuming he/she wanted the scrolling to work.

Answer (score 1):

Other div is going down because all .scrollbox are behaving as **table cell**. 
Another, simple solution if you want to use flexbox is below. I have edited your code to work with flexbox.

```
 <div class="scroll-con">
  <div class="Scrollbox">1</div>
  <div class="Scrollbox">2</div>
  <div class="Scrollbox">3</div>
  <div class="Scrollbox">4</div>
</div>

.scroll-con {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.Scrollbox {
   background:rgba(237, 41, 57,0.6);

   border:1px solid #ffffff;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   width:300px;
   height:250px;
   transition: height 1s ease;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: center;

   font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; 

 }

 .Scrollbox:hover {
    height:500px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is a flex box?

Comment: A simple google search for `flexbox` brings up this page as the first result - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Your transition was doing weird things, so I removed it.

**EDIT:**

I changed the code based on your requirements.  I'm not sure why your `overflow-y: scroll;` is in there.  I assumed you wanted these to scroll, so I took out some of the previous stuff I did.

I left the explanation below in case you're looking for something else with that `overflow-y: scroll;` stuff.  It might help you in the future.

The new code is just using the class on the `td` and vertically aligning it to the top.  This is better than targeting all `tr`'s to do this, as this may give you undesirable results elsewhere in another table you're using.

I changed the class to be all lower case as well, since most people do it this way when [naming css classes](http://bdavidxyz.com/blog/how-to-name-css-classes/).

> **PREVIOUS SOLUTION INFORMATION:**
>
> One way you can achieve this is to put the `css` class on the `td`
>   element prior.  You then change the height of the inner `div` and set
>   the `td` to have `overflow-y:scroll` as desired.  But you also have to
>   make the `td` element `display:block`, which I don't really like
>   doing.  I would suggest changing these to `div`s that mimic what your
>   `td`s are doing.

```css
td.scrollbox
{
  vertical-align: top;
}

td.scrollbox div
{
  background:rgba(237, 41, 57,0.6);
  width:300px;
  height: 250px;
  border:1px solid #ffffff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; 
}

td.scrollbox:hover div
{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="scrollbox">
      <div>1</div>
    </td>
    <td class="scrollbox">
      <div>2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="scrollbox">
      <div>3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="scrollbox">
      <div>4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My issue is that i have a general td code that affects the entire page. And then when I try doing the td as scroll boxes they take the design of the general td and not the scroll box class. it does become a scrollbox an hoverable it just doesnt inherit the design I need and the only way I found around it was placing a div inside the td. unless you know a way to fix this issue

Comment: @Cheyenne, I don't really understand what you're talking about.  I'd probably have to see more code and further explanation.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your requirement. You don't care about the `td` becoming scrollable? Why do you have `overflow-y: scroll;`?